# Issues / Steps in downgrading silverlight 4 app to silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

What steps does it take to download a Silverlight 4 application to Silverlight 3.

I can't develop any longer with Beta 4 and made a wrong assumption that VS2010 RC would be able to run Sivlerlight Beta 4 - which it [unfortunately can't](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/02/09/faq-silverlight-and-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx). [VS2010 RC which was just released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx) can only currently work with SL3. (hoping/expecting someone to hack it to work but right now it doesn't)

So I'm wondering what are the steps to download Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 3 and what do I lose and what should I watch out for.

(I realize that the answer is somewhat related to the 'opposite' of the feature list for SL4 but there's other issues - such as updating projects etc.) and perhaps some subtle things to watch out for that don't get caught by the compiler.

**EDIT: IMPORTANT. There is now a workaround to get SL4 running in VS2010 RC**
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://sorokoletov.com/2010/02/hate-2-wait-silverlight-4-beta-2-vs-2010-rc/

The only problem I've seen so far is I cannot use 'dynamic' - which is fine for me.
I get this error when running this code:

```
 dynamic userState = e.UserState;
 userState.dfo();
```

One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to go back to Beta 2 instead and wait for the next public release of SL4 before moving to RC?  It would save you re-coding back to SL3 which surely you'll regret as soon as VS2010 and SL4 are RTM?

Comment: going back to SL3 was just a momentary whim... it looks like a big endeavor. as soon as i realized I'd lose string formatting for bound data values it was game over!

Comment: i just clean installed my whole machine. cant decide whether to abandon silverlight for now and upgrade to RC - or abandon vs2010 for my other projects :-/

Comment: If you're talking about using string.format as a converter when {Binding}, then yes you can still do that in SL3

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

> A quick warning for Silverlight
>   developers: Silverlight 3 projects are
>   supported with the Visual Studio 2010
>   Release Candidate build but
>   Silverlight 4 projects are not, and
>   won't be until the next public
>   Silverlight 4 release. Thus, if you
>   are doing active Silverlight 4
>   development, Microsoft recommends
>   staying with the Visual Studio 2010
>   Beta 2 build for now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was a pipedream of mine. I only started developing with SL4 and the downgrading appears to be a very painful procedure.

They just added way too many cool features !!!

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx